# How does concatenation of two string literals work?

Tags: c, string

```
char* a="dsa" "qwe";
printf("%s", a);
```

output: `dsaqwe`

My question is why does this thing work. If I give a space or nothing in between two string literals it concatenates the string literals.

How is this working?

Comment: Please put something real in question titles. I edited this for you, please see if it fits.

Comment: As a side effect of this, pairs of double quotes embedded in string literals are ignored, as in `"dsa""qwe"` `:)`

Answer (score 55, accepted):

It's defined by the ISO C standard, adjacent string literals are combined into a single one.

The language is a little dry (it is a standard after all) but section `6.4.5 String literals` of `C11` states:

> In translation phase 6, the multibyte character sequences specified by any sequence of adjacent character and identically-prefixed wide string literal tokens are concatenated into a single multibyte character sequence.

This is also mentioned in `5.1.1.2 Translation phases, point 6` of the same standard, though a little more succinctly:

> Adjacent string literal tokens are concatenated.

This basically means that `"abc" "def"` is no different to `"abcdef"`.

It's often useful for making long strings while still having nice formatting, something like:

```
const char *myString = "This is a really long "
                       "string and I don't want "
                       "to make my lines in the "
                       "editor too long, because "
                       "I'm basically anal retentive :-)";
```

Comment: I am afraid I have an even worse case of anal retention as I would feel obligated to use `const char *` for this definition `:)`

Answer (score 13):

And to answer your unasked question, "What is this good for?"

For one thing, you can put constants in string literals. You can write

```
#define FIRST "John"
#define LAST "Doe"

const char* name = FIRST " " LAST;
const char* salutation = "Dear " FIRST ",";
```

and then if you'll need to change the name later, you'll only have to change it in one spot.
Things like that.

Comment: Good example. You might add another one with the `printf` and `scanf` macros defined in `<inttypes.h>`: `PRId32`, ...

Answer (score 6):

You answered your own question.

> If I give a space or nothing in between two string literals it concatenates the string literals.

That's one of the features of the C syntax.

Answer (score 1):

ISO C standard `§5.1.1.2` says:-

> 1. Adjacent string literal tokens are concatenated.
> 2. White-space characters separating tokens are no longer significant.

Comment: Actually, that second one there is a phase 7 activity, done _after_ the combining of adjacent string literals in phase 6. Adjacent in this sense means ignore white space anyway. However, +1 for the first one.