# concatenation of strings with literals using + and space

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [concatenation of two string literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120944/concatenation-of-two-string-literals)

**Case 1** `"hello" "world"` (NO ERROR)

**Case 2** `"hello"+"world"` (ERROR)

I know that the `+` operator must atleat have one of its operand as `string type`,not `string literal`.

Thing is,both of the cases doesnt make sense,since we can include it into a `single literal` !

Why is Case 1 allowed then!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Case 1 is allowed because C++ basically considers adjacent literals to be the same literal, i.e. the code `"hello" "world"` is transformed into `"helloworld"` early on in the parsing.

Comment: oh..so stupid of me to forget tht..thxx

Answer (score 0):

Case 1, as you call it, is a convenient way to let string constants span several lines or be broken up into easily identified parts.

It's there to make your life easier.

Assuming that `+` should have the same semantics when used with string constants is a mistake. Especially in C, where `string` isn't an available type.