# What is under the hood of x = 'y' 'z' in Python?

Tags: python, string, syntax, concatenation, python-internals

If you run `x = 'y' 'z'` in Python, you get `x` set to `'yz'`, which means that some kind of string concatenation is occurring when Python sees multiple strings next to each other.

But what kind of concatenation is this?
Is it actually running `'y' + 'z'` or is it running `''.join('y','z')` or something else?

Comment: I think this is part of the lexer/parser. When Python parses the file and sees adjacent strings, it treats it as a single string.

Comment: If there is a difference between the `'x' + 'y'` and `''.join(..)` statements, you could try out if you get different results. What happens, for example, if you throw in a variable?

Comment: You have a misconception that, when Python does things, it has to do them via constructs of Python.

Comment: [C does this too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120944/how-does-concatenation-of-two-string-literals-work). Since  the 1970s. For the history of why Dennis Ritchie designed it that way, see [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/254984/on-concatenating-adjacent-string-literals).

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The Python *parser* interprets that as one string. This is well documented in the [Lexical Analysis documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literal-concatenation):

> ### String literal concatenation
>
> Multiple adjacent string literals (delimited by whitespace), possibly using different quoting conventions, are allowed, and their meaning is the same as their concatenation. Thus, `"hello" 'world'` is equivalent to `"helloworld"`.

The compiled Python code sees just the one string object; you can see this by asking Python to produce an AST of such strings:

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.dump(ast.parse("'hello' 'world'", mode='eval').body)
"Str(s='helloworld')"
```

In fact, it is the very act of building the AST that triggers the concatenation, as the parse tree is traversed, see the [`parsestrplus()` function](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/927cca0b9337/Python/ast.c#l3548) in the AST C source.

The feature is specifically aimed at reducing the need for backslashes; use it to break up a string across physical lines when still within a [*logical* line](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#logical-lines):

```
print('Hello world!', 'This string is spans just one '
      'logical line but is broken across multiple physical '
      'source lines.')
```

Multiple physical lines can [implicitly be joined](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#implicit-line-joining) into one physical line by using parentheses, square brackets or curly braces.

This [string concatenation feature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal#String_literal_concatenation) was copied from C, but [Guido van Rossum is on record regretting adding it to Python](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2013-May/020527.html). That post kicked of a long and very interesting thread, with a lot of support for removing the feature altogether.

Comment: +1 Doesn't this apply only to strings in the same line?

Comment: @heltonbiker: it applies to strings on the same **logical** line. That can span multiple physical lines, if backslashes, parentheses or brackets are involved.

Comment: Note that concatenation of adjacent strings in source is largely a C-family tradition.

Comment: @RussellBorogove: indeed, and since it doesn't offer the same advantages in Python as it does in C (for use in macros) it looks like its days in Python are numbered.

Comment: I have been bitten by the problem mentioned by Guido too. Particularly in long lists where each element is on a separate line (`a = ['this', 'that' 'other']` for example).  On the other hand, I do like being able to say `'foo %s' ' bar %d' % (a, b)` instead of `('foo %s' + ' bar %d') % (a, b)` (imagine all the strings are on different lines).

Comment: @Alok--: hence the interesting discussion on the Python-Ideas list. A new literal concatenation token (`...`) was proposed to handle the issue of precedence. There are a fair number of posts to read there, but it is worth it if this sort of thing interests you!

Comment: Yeah, reading through the thread now (there goes my hour or more!).  It's very interesting.  Thanks.

Comment: Uhm. I personally don't think that literal concatenation will be removed; at least not in the next few years. If they wanted to remove it they should have done that when making python3.0. Right now, with a lot of people already fighting with backwards compatibility introducing an other break may make things worse. They may be removed in python4.0, whenever this will be released...

Comment: @Bakuriu: I'm actually surprised at how strongly Guido was in support of removing it in that thread, given that a [full-on PEP to remove it from Python 3](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3126/) had already been rejected 6 years earlier.

Answer (score 8):

The strings are being concatenated by the python parser before anything is executed, so its not really like `'y' + 'z'` or `''.join('y','z')`, except that it has the same effect.