# Surround emoji with spaces

Tags: python, regex, python-2.x, emoji

I used [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26568722/remove-unicode-emoji-using-re-in-python) to make a regex that would find emojis in a string of text and simply stick some space characters on either side. my regex code:

```
try:
    # Wide UCS-4 build
    oRes = re.compile(u'['
        u'\U0001F300-\U0001F64F'
        u'\U0001F680-\U0001F6FF'
        u'\u2600-\u26FF\u2700-\u27BF]+', 
        re.UNICODE)
except re.error:
    # Narrow UCS-2 build
    oRes = re.compile(u'('
        u'\ud83c[\udf00-\udfff]|'
        u'\ud83d[\udc00-\ude4f\ude80-\udeff]|'
        u'[\u2600-\u26FF\u2700-\u27BF])+', 
        re.UNICODE)

s2 = oRE.sub(r'  \1  ', s1)
```

However, I am getting some really odd behaviour where emojis are being removed, as in the example below. Any advice would be appreciated. I am using Python on a MacBook. Thanks.

**INPUT**

هيلاري كلينتون "متنحة" وتشير إلى عملية غش في ولاية بانسيلفانيا العتيقة قائلة: "عند فرز الاصوات ..قطعوا الكهربا ✋" #ابو_الياس

**OUTPUT**

هيلاري كلينتون "متنحة" وتشير إلى عملية غش في ولاية بانسيلفانيا العتيقة قائلة: "عند فرز الاصوات ..قطعوا الكهربا   ✋  " #ابو_الياس

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am using 2.7.

Comment: You're welcome. I don't know much about unicode in python though so someone else will have to answer your question.

Comment: Which of the two branches is executing on your system and causing the problem? If `len(u'\U0001f600')` returns 2 then you are using UCS2, if it returns 1 it's UCS4.

Comment: @SMeyer the OP linked to a post where someone already helped them figure this out. "wow, thanks! It seems the USC-4 build works properly!"(from op)

Comment: just for completeness, len(u'\U0001f600') returns 2.

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me once I correct the placement of the round brackets in your regular expressions. In the `try` block, you need round brackets around the whole thing if you want to create the group `\1` at all; in the `except` block, the round brackets need to *include* the `+`, otherwise the `\1` group will only capture the first of multiple relevant characters.

```
import re
with open('input.txt', 'rb') as f:
    s1 = f.read().decode('utf-8').strip()

try:
    # Wide UCS-4 build
    oRes = re.compile(u'(['
        u'\U0001F300-\U0001F64F'
        u'\U0001F680-\U0001F6FF'
        u'\u2600-\u26FF\u2700-\u27BF]+)', 
        re.UNICODE)
except re.error:
    # Narrow UCS-2 build
    oRes = re.compile(u'(('
        u'\ud83c[\udf00-\udfff]|'
        u'\ud83d[\udc00-\ude4f\ude80-\udeff]|'
        u'[\u2600-\u26FF\u2700-\u27BF])+)', 
        re.UNICODE)

s2 = oRes.sub(r'  \1  ', s1)

with open('output.txt', 'wb') as f:
    f.write((s1+'\n').encode('utf-8'))
    f.write((s2+'\n').encode('utf-8'))
```

As for the reversal of your characters, that must be an artifact of some step in your input/output or copy/paste chain not correctly handling the right-to-left nature of Arabic. It doesn't happen for me. The results look good when I open `output.txt` in TextWrangler on my MacBook.

Comment: Good catch. I missed that the `+` wasn't in the capture.

Comment: I think this is incorrect in the except block. Note that the brackets include OR statements (|), which means that in the current code you only apply the plus to the last OR case.

Comment: Hmm, @SMeyer is right. Actually to surround *each* emoji character with spaces (if that's the aim) requires the `+` to be removed.  To surround each emoji *sequence* with spaces requires extra parentheses.  I'll put the extra ones in because the `try` block suggests that surrounding whole sequences is the aim.

Comment: the aim is to surround **each** emoji - so that means the + should be removed i guess.

Comment: "As for the reversal of your characters" ??? sorry, I did not mention any reversal?

Comment: Your INPUT and OUTPUT look like the characters might have reversed character order relative to each other. The emoji is near the beginning and preceded by `#"` in the output, whereas it's near the end and *followed* by `"#` in the input.   The arabic is sometimes the same, sometimes slightly different, which I presume is the result of characters being reversed and then differently grouped into words.