# String syntax allows two strings in a row with no operator?

Tags: python, syntax

I just discovered what I thought was a typo but Python accepts it.

```
foo = {'a': 'b'}
foo.get('a'"")
```

returns `'b'`. Where in Python is `'a'""` defined as a valid parameter to a function?

Comment: In [the language reference](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literal-concatenation)? See also [an attempt to remove it](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3126/).

Answer (score 2):

Python concatenates all consecutive strings. It doesn't matter if that's in a function or elsewhere.

See the [*String literal concatenation* section](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literal-concatenation) of the reference documentation:

> Multiple adjacent string literals (delimited by whitespace), possibly using different quoting conventions, are allowed, and their meaning is the same as their concatenation.

This is done at the parsel level; the final bytecode stores just the one string object. See [What is under the hood of x = 'y' 'z' in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26433138/what-is-under-the-hood-of-x-y-z-in-python)

The feature was copied from C. From a [(failed) proposal to remove the feature](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3126/):

> Many Python parsing rules are intentionally compatible with C. [...] In C, implicit concatenation is the only way to join strings without using a (run-time) function call to store into a variable.

The feature is very useful when producing long strings:

```
long_value = (
    'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy fox and kept '
    'the string within the 80 character boundary.'
)
```