# How should I write the code that prints the plus sign enclosed in quotation marks?

Tags: python

I could not print the plus sign enclosed in quotation marks.

Tried the following:

```py
print("String Concatenation is done with the "+" sign.")

print("String Concatenation is done with the '"+"' sign.")

print("String Concatenation is done with the "\"+\"" sign.")

print("String Concatenation is done with the "\"+"\" sign.")

print("String Concatenation is done with the """ "+" """ sign.")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using quotation marks inside quotation marks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050355/using-quotation-marks-inside-quotation-marks)

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the quotation marks like this:

```
print("String Concatenation is done with the \"+\" sign.")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use "\". The sign \ "excludes" the next character if it is quotation marks!

```
print("\"Hello World\", said Harry")
```

Another way would be to use *'* at the start and beginning:

```
print('"Hello World", said Harry')
```

Answer (score -1):

After doing other trials-and-errors, finally came up with the right solution:

print("String Concatenation is done with the "'"+"'" sign.")

plus sign should be enclosed in double-single-double quotation marks.

Comment: That does work, because in Python you can place string literals next to each other and the parser concatenates them into one literal (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26433138/what-is-under-the-hood-of-x-y-z-in-python?noredirect=1&lq=1). So your expression equates to `"String Concatenation is done with the "`, followed by `'"+"'`, followed by `" sign."`, and the three are combined by the parser. It works, but the other answers people have posted here are the more conventional ways to handle this.

Comment: It is a solution. But I wouldn't call it "right" but "weird."

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).