# QSqlQuery ctor or prepare() syntax when more than 1 string literal

Tags: c++, qt

In a peer review I stumbled across some lines of Qt and more precisely on QSqlQuery that I never experienced before

```
QSqlQuery query(my_db);
query.prepare("SELECT * FROM Result "
              "WHERE Tag=:some_tag AND Name=:my_name");
```

I was astonished by the syntax `prepare("PlainOldCChain1" "PlainOldCChain2")`

What kind of C++ object is `"PlainOldCChain1" "PlainOldCChain2"` (I would have thought to some Initializer list but without { , } I am a little bit lost. I found only the prototype `bool prepare(const QString & query)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjacent string literals with white space in between are simply concatenated.

```
query.prepare("SELECT * FROM Result "
              "WHERE Tag=:some_tag AND Name=:my_name");
```

is exactly the same as

```
query.prepare("SELECT * FROM Result WHERE Tag=:some_tag AND Name=:my_name");
```

---

Also see: [How does concatenation of two string literals work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120944/how-does-concatenation-of-two-string-literals-work)

Comment: OK thanks. My mistake. It is fun how we can forget such simple things [Another SO Post on adjacent strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120944/how-does-concatenation-of-two-string-literals-work)

Comment: Agreed, that is a more informative answer, have added for future reference.