# How to explain the C code: char *s = "hello " "world";

Tags: c, string-literals

I tried the following C code by accident:

```
char *str = "hello " "world";
```

It's right, but I can't understand. How to explain this instrument?

Comment: What have you found out yourself? What does your C book say? Online tutorials? Your compiler? Anything? And how is that related to compiler construction? (and it is not gcc specific).

Comment: Adjacent string literals get concatenated. You could've looked it up.

Answer (score 0):

According to the C Standard (5.1.1.2 Translation phases)

> 6. Adjacent string literal tokens are concatenated.

So after this translation phase this code snippet

```
char *str = "hello " "world";
```

is adjusted to

```
char *str = "hello world";
```

As result the pointer `str` points to the first character of the string literal `"hello world"`.

Answer (score 0):

C standard says these literals are to be concatenated.

More details in earlier answer:
[How does concatenation of two string literals work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120944/how-does-concatenation-of-two-string-literals-work)