# How do I use variadic arguments with printf in a macro?

Tags: c, printf, c-preprocessor, variadic-macros

I have found no way to merge the first printf into the second:

```
unsigned get_time_now(void) {return 1;}
#define DEBUG_PRINT 1
#define debug_tcprintf(fmt, ...) do { \
            if (DEBUG_PRINT) { \
                unsigned p_time_now = get_time_now(); \
                printf ("%u ms ", p_time_now); \
                printf(fmt, __VA_ARGS__); \
            } \
        } while (0)
```

I need to get this done to get an atomic debug_tcprintf. The macro above has been taken from [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644868/c-define-macro-for-debug-printing).

I am doing code in XC that runs on an XMOS multi-logical-core processor. It compiles XC, C and C++, but the code example is from a C code part. It is similar for XC except that it has a timer defined in the language.

If it's not possible to merge the two in one printf, an option may perhaps be to create a string and use sprintf instead? I'd rather not, since such an array might easily overflow.

Comment: For starters, why not just `printf("%u ms " fmt, p_time_now, __VA_ARGS__);`?

Comment: Yeah, deleted comment.  I see what you are doing. The "atomic" printf statement made me raise an eyebrow.  That means something different to me :)

Comment: @MichaelDorgan: Sure, it'll take a bit longer until the OP will realize that no such thing exists.

Comment: Hold on, I added an extra comma. Testing now

Comment: @ØyvindTeig: [works for me](https://wandbox.org/permlink/50Kdj0Jwgib6QgHV)

Comment: @ØyvindTeig Did you code a `,` between `"%u ms "` and `fmt`?

Comment: THANKS A LOT! It works and is atomic! I didn't see that combination. What's the explanation behind not any comma before fmt?

Comment: why to you need `do{...}while(0)` there? `{...}` would be sufficient.

Comment: @ØyvindTeig when you put two string literals back-to-back, the compiler combines them during the pre-processor pass. this is called string concatenation. more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12120988/3961271).

Comment: @Serge do..while wrapped around a multi-statement pre-processor macro is considered best practice. if you just used braces, you would need to omit the semicolon when invoking the macro which leads to inconsistent style.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use string concatenation and [token pasting](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html). Notice in the snippet below there is no comma after the first string literal -- this is intentional.

```
#define debug_tcprintf(fmt, ...) do { \
    if (DEBUG_PRINT_HTTPD) { \
        unsigned p_time_now = get_time_now (); \
        printf ("%u ms " fmt, p_time_now, ##__VA_ARGS__); \
    } \
} while (0)
```

The string concatenation allows you to prepend the `"%u ms "` portion onto the supplied format string. Token pasting (the `##` operator) accounts for the possibility of your macro being invoked with or without additional variadic arguments (beyond just the format string).

This only works if you call the macro with a string literal as the format string.

---

Addendum: The way token-pasting is used in this example is actually a gcc extension to the standard C pre-processor. If you are not using the gcc compiler, you may need to omit the `##` operator. The downside to this is that you then cannot call your macro with only one argument; for example, `debug_tcprintf ("hello world")` will not work. A simple workaround is to use `debug_tcprintf ("%s", "hello world")` in such a scenario.

Comment: I'd also remove the `p_time_now` temp var - it doesn't do anything and could cause warnings if printf() were ever redefined on a release build.

Comment: String concatenation and token pasting won't work if the passed-in format isn't a string literal.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: That's true, but format strings should probably never ever be anything other than literals.

Comment: @AndrewHenle that's why my answer says "This only works if you call the macro with a string literal as the format string."

Comment: Yes, I konw that. But it's ok to use debug_tcprintf ("%s", "Hello World\n"); once I got used to it.

Comment: @ØyvindTeig that isn't necessary, that's what the token pasting (the `##` operator) is for. you can simply call `debug_tcprintf ("Hello World\n");`.

Comment: @ØyvindTeig the token pasting accounts for the possibility of the macro being called with or without the additional variadic arguments.

Comment: The XC compiler causes "warning: Less than necessary 2 argument(s) in macro call "debug_tprintf2("Hello world\n")"" if I do the single "Hello World"

Comment: @ØyvindTeig ah, in that case, it is possible that your compiler doesn't fully implement token pasting.

Comment: Interesting. I'll take this to theXCore Exchange group and ask there. Back later

Comment: The XC compiler (in an .xc file) does not accept the ##__VA_ARGS__ and issues error: Not a valid preprocessing token ","init]\n"" That's why I didn't include it initially. However, when it compiles C (in a .c file) it is being accepted. So to make it general I'd have to take the lower route.

Comment: There's a problem with `__VA_ARGS__`: You always get the comma before, even if you have *no* variable arguments. There are currently no portable ways to have an optional comma.

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow FYI, in a standard C Preprocessor, the macro `debug_tcprintf(fmt, ...)` requires _two arguments_; `...` requires _at least one_ argument.  Furthermore, in a standard C Preprocessor, `, ## __VA_ARGS__` usually isn't valid as the paste usually doesn't result in a valid token.  What you're actually using is a gnu cpp _extension_ that allows one less argument to be taken, and a special meaning to be given to `, ## __VA_ARGS__` that in such calls results in the comma being removed.

Comment: Thanks to all of you!

Comment: @KerrekSB "There are currently no portable ways to have an optional comma."  That's not quite true.  You can: (a) define the macro as `debug_tcprintf(...)`, detect whether there's one or more than one arguments (up to some n), in the former case use the one without a comma, and in the latter case use the rest with a comma; that approach requires multiple macros.  Or (b) you can just use `debug_tcprintf(fmt, extra)`, _use_ it like `debug_tcprintf("%d%s",(,a,b))` or `debug_tcprintf("---",())`, and use supporting macros to expand `extra`.

Comment: ...here it's probably not worth it; simply using an idiom `debug_tcprintf("---",0)` would pass an extra argument in that's ignored, but that's safe.