# Append symbol name when using custom section attribute

Tags: c, gcc, linker, ld

Below is a fragment of code I'm using for an embedded system. I pass the `-ffunction-sections` and `-fdata-sections` options to `gcc`:

```
#define FAST_DATA __attribute__((section(".fast.data")))

          int a1 = 1;
          int a2 = 1;
FAST_DATA int a3 = 1;
FAST_DATA int a4 = 1;
```

The linker will allocate these symbols as below (map file):

```
 .data.a1       0x20000020        0x4 ./main.o
                0x20000020                a1

 .data.a2       0x20000024        0x4 ./main.o
                0x20000024                a2

 .fast.data     0x10000010        0x8 ./main.o
                0x10000010                a4
                0x10000014                a3
```

If for example I don't use the variable `a2`, the linker will discard it (I pass `--gc-sections` to `ld`).
But if I use `a3` and don't use `a4`, then `a4` will not be discarded. I guess that's because it is placed in the same section as `a3`.

If I define `a3` and `a4` in separate .c files, they will be put in two different sections, with the same name `.fast.data`, but for each file. The garbage collector will work as expected.

Is there any way to tell `gcc` to append the symbol name even when using `__attribute__((section("...")))`? 
For `a4` in my case that would result in `.fast.data.a4`. 
In the linker script I will catch all `*(.fast.data*)`.

I have a large code base using custom sections a lot and manual modifications to each declaration would not be desirable.

Answer (score 3):

If no one else has a better idea, here is a kludge for you:

```
#define DECLARE_FAST_DATA(type, name) \
    __attribute__((section(".fast.data." #name))) type name
```

usage:

```
int a1 = 1;
int a2 = 1;
DECLARE_FAST_DATA(int, a3) = 1;
DECLARE_FAST_DATA(int, a4);
```

This uses the standard C features of "[stringification](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/cpp/Stringification.html)" and "[string literal concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120944/how-does-concatenation-of-two-string-literals-work)" to synthesize the section attribute you want.

Answer (score 0):

What about extending your macro?

```
#define FAST_DATA(_a,_b,_c) \
  __attribute__((section(".fast.data." #_b))) _a _b = _c
```